# security libraries for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures, configuration

I have some extended classes (utilizing both HMAC and cryptographic tech), and I'm hoping to utilize them for a new product's database from said database's stored procedures (inclusive of time logging, user-event logging, etc.) under SQL Server.

Can anyone recommend a resource detailing the best ways to achieve this or optionally advise a more preferable approach to low-level, data-layer access-security that includes automated interaction logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom source libraries accessible to SQL Server... no problem says Microsoft... anything developed in C# / VB.NET can be taken via CIL / CLR directly into SQL Server to be used as a custom library, etc. within stored procedures, etc.

I'm off to finalize & test...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the option of encrypting at the application layer? This will ensure that it's encrypted going over the wire as well as ensuring that a nosy DBA doesn't see the unencrypted information using Profiler or a trace.

Comment: I would pick one layer and do the encryption at that layer only, if you can. Simpler is better.

Comment: Even though you've convinced me the application layer is where I should focus security efforts, there are other potential libraries (XPath manipulation and such) I'd still like to manipulate within stored procedures, as I'm much more developer and much less DBA(DBAnthing), is there a way to accomlish that?

Comment: Per my 'answer' below I'll be doing both now... encrypting at the application layer and decrypting at the stored procedure level -- perfect.